# Issue applying patch with Composer and Drupal

Tags: composer-php, drupal-8

Some clarification is needed since I wasn't thorough enough.

**I have contrib module Lazyloader.**

- I'm applying this patch: https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-11-29/lazyloader-LQIP-2905310-6.patch from this issue https://www.drupal.org/project/lazyloader/issues/2905310

This patch created random SVG images which we don't like. So we wanted to update the code and create a Grey SVG placeholder image.
**Using the code from the Patch I made some updates and I want to basically do the following:**

Install Lazyloader

- Patch with https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-11-29/lazyloader-LQIP-2905310-6.patch
- Patch with my own custom code, which requires the previous patch.

When I apply a self-made patch, 3 new directories are created,but this shouldn't happen:

- modules/contrib/lazyloader/b/
- modules/contrib/lazyloader/contrib/
- modules/contrib/lazyloader/modules/

**The module is already installed under modules/contrib/lazyloader and the only directory that should be created is modules/contrib/lazyloader/css and the file name.css**

I tried no prefix (can't apply patch if I use this)

```
git diff --staged > name.patchhttps://www.drupal.org/project/lazyloader/issues/2905310
```

I apply patch with ...

```
lando composer update drupal/lazyload
```

... but it creates a new directory that I didn't include in the patch.

I found [this issue](https://github.com/adam-dg/d8-quickstart/commit/38d513f6d6e8a58c0431a62aa19038ceea79e911) but I'm not sure if this is affecting my issue.

I believe it's an issue with patch level and `cweagans/composer-patches`.

This is my Patch

```
diff --git a/modules/contrib/lazyloader/css/grey_svg.css b/modules/contrib/lazyloader/css/grey_svg.css
new file mode 100644
index 000000000..573a3bb74
--- /dev/null
+++ b/modules/contrib/lazyloader/css/grey_svg.css
@@ -0,0 +1,3 @@
+.lazyload {
+  background-color: lightgrey;
+}
diff --git a/modules/contrib/lazyloader/lazyloader.libraries.yml b/modules/contrib/lazyloader/lazyloader.libraries.yml
index 99e023f00..ef4d1c6ff 100644
--- a/modules/contrib/lazyloader/lazyloader.libraries.yml
+++ b/modules/contrib/lazyloader/lazyloader.libraries.yml
@@ -15,3 +15,8 @@ lazysizes-min.cdn:
     gpl-compatible: true
   js:
     https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lazysizes/2.0.0/lazysizes.min.js: { type: external, minified: true }
+
+udesa-grey-svg:
+  css:
+    theme:
+      css/grey_svg.css: {}
diff --git a/modules/contrib/lazyloader/lazyloader.module b/modules/contrib/lazyloader/lazyloader.module
index 24998ed18..dc872356f 100644
--- a/modules/contrib/lazyloader/lazyloader.module
+++ b/modules/contrib/lazyloader/lazyloader.module
@@ -118,3 +118,10 @@ function lazyloader_libraries_info() {

   return $libraries;
 }
+
+/**
+ * Implements hook_libraries_info().
+ */
+function lazyloader_page_attachments(array &$page) {
+  $page['#attached']['library'][] = 'lazyloader/udesa-grey-svg';
+}
```

Also this is my composer.json Patches

```
    "drupal/lazyloader": {
        "Provide option to use a image style as the placeholder image": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-11-29/lazyloader-LQIP-2905310-6.patch",
        "Create black SVG as placeholder image": "patches/lazyloader/lazyloader-create-black-svg.patch"
    }
```

Patch name is not the issue, I've been toying with several of them

SOLUTIO > I what what the solution informed

1- Install module with --prefer source with the Patch I wanted from drupal.org
2- Went into modules/contrib/lazyloader
3- I was in detached head branch with the changes from the patch
4- made my own changes since I needed the patch from drupal.org in the first palce
5- created my own patch with my changes

Working perfectly!

Comment: May you upload your patch somewhere (https://pastebin.com/) or somewhere else ? May you also add the line from your `composer.json` ? Should looks like `"patches": {
    "drupal/lazyloader": {
        "Your patch description": "./patches/your_patch_file.patch"
    }
}`

Comment: Please improve the question: Which (of the 3) directories is created? All of them? You don't want them to be created? What exactly is inside the patch? Please add the patch itself to the question.

Comment: I updated my question, I hope it's a bit clearer now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your patch should be local to the module git repo. The paths have to look something like this:

```
diff --git a/lazyloader/css/grey_svg.css b/lazyloader/css/grey_svg.css
```

Instead of:

```
diff --git a/modules/contrib/lazyloader/css/grey_svg.css b/modules/contrib/lazyloader/css/grey_svg.css
```

The path to the contrib module is taken from your composer.json (drupal/lazyloader)

Make sure you're using the contrib module git repo to create the patch (not drupal core). https://www.drupal.org/node/707484

Starting from scratch, the process should be something like this:

1. From your project root folder, install lazyloader from source using composer:

```
composer require 'drupal/lazyloader:^1.0' --prefer-source
```

2. Make your changes to the code using your favorite IDE.
3. Create the patch:

```
cd web/modules/contrib/lazyloader
git diff --staged > name.patch
mv name.patch ../../../../patches/lazyloader/lazyloader-create-black-svg.patch
```

4. Your composer.json looks good. Next time you run composer install or composer update your patch will be installed.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean, but how do I make it possible? Does it depend from where I create the patch? Should I create it from /modules/contrib/lazyloader?

Where is the path in composer.json taken from? I haven't been able to see any paths there.
Also, thanks for taking the time to reply!

Comment: I'm assuming this is happening because you're using the drupal git repo to create a patch for a contrib module. You need to install lazyloader with composer adding --prefer-source at the end (so you'll get the git repo of lazyloader), move to the module folder and run your 'git diff ...' command.

Comment: I did some updates to my question. I wasn't clear enough, because I'm updating a patch already made by someone else, that is why I wanted to create a custom patch to be stored on my local code, but it uses a patch already updated to Drupal, I linked the issue too

Comment: I don't think that makes any difference, although I'd only apply one custom patch merging the first patch and your modifications in one file. The problem remains on how you're creating your patch. Are you using the source files of the lazyloader module? Are you running 'git diff...' inside the lazyloader dir?

Comment: I wanted to apply the patch and then do my own changes, but only for my project, not uploading the patch to drupal, having instead a local dir with /patches/ladyloader/mypatch.patch
I was making the changes on the Project git, instead should I make them inside lazyloader in their own git? Which is branch alpha-112134?

Comment: If you're doing it right your git repo shouldn't include the contrib modules. 'git diff' compares the current git branch with the local changes. So yes, you should do the changes inside your local version of the git lazyloader, which you can get with the command on 1). If the drupal patch is applied to lazyloader and you make additional changes on it, your final patch will contain all the changes. So, before running again composer install to apply your local patch, remove the contrib patch from your composer.json.

Comment: It worked @sam711. I did what you said.
1- Install contrib module with Original Patch with --prefer-source
2- went into modules/contrib/lazyloader
3- made my changes
4- git diff --staged > name.patch

Comment: Glad you get it sorted!